# undefined is not a function in asset pipeline

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails-4, asset-pipeline

I load the breakon.js in  `render 'layouts/lms_header'`

But I got `undefined is not a function` on  the  `$(window).setBreakpoints();`

I have no idea why I got this error.

I think I've loaded the `jquery` and  `breakpoints.js` already.

I use the `breakpoint` library by `http://xoxco.com/projects/code/breakpoints/example.html`

### Layout.haml

```
!!!
%html
  %head
    %title BalanceCafe
    = stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all'
    = javascript_include_tag 'application'
    = csrf_meta_tags
    =render 'layouts/lms_header'
```

### application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_self
//= require welcome
```

### welcome.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  return $(function() {

    $(window).bind("enterBreakpoint1024", function() {
      $("#log").append("<p>Entering 1024 breakpoint</p>");
    });
    $(window).setBreakpoints();
});
```

Comment: *"I think I've loaded the jquery and  breakpoints.js already"* - Can't you just open browser console and ensure it they are loaded or not..?

Comment: yes, they are loaded, but I cannot ensure the are loaded before this call.